# colorbox bug - close colorbox from a link or button

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I open the popup by calling

```
$.colorbox({ href: "notification.aspx" });
```

In notification.aspx I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
...
<a id="btnClose">OK</a>
```

The popup was shown fine, but when I click the button it gives a JavaScript error.

In the main page's javascript I have

```
$('#btnClose').live('click', function () {
  alert('closing...'); // Alert shown as expected
  $.colorbox.close(); // Nothing happens, no JavaScript error
  //$.fn.colorbox.close(); // same
  //parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); // same
  //$.colorbox.remove(); // same
  //$('#cboxClose').click(); // same
  //$('#cboxOverlay').click(); // same
});
```

I am just trying to close the popup.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I got it working somehow, I'll find out what made it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$.colorbox.close()` is the correct way to close colorbox, do not listen to these other comments.  The problem is that you are loading colorbox a second time.  Remove the `jquery.colorbox.js` script block from `notification.aspx`.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks, but if I remove it from notification.aspx, it would say $.colorbox is undefined

Comment: And why is that?  Are you loading multiple versions of jQuery?  You are doing something you shouldn't be, then papering over the problem by simply loading the libraries again.  Figure out why $.colorbox is not defined and resolve that instead.

Comment: That's it!! I didn't realise including jquery twice!! Thanks Jack!

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
<a href='#' onclick='parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false;'>Close</a>
```

Comment: This is the one you need if you are using .iframe within colorbox. parent.$.colorbox.close(); Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.colorbox({

                inline:true,
                href:'notification.aspx',

                onClosed:function(){ alert('closing');                  

                    $.colorbox.remove();
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: I tried that as well... nothing works this is very weird... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your comments.

This is really weird, but after fiddling around I found this does it

```
$('#btnClose').live('click', function () {
  $.colorbox.remove(); // You have to remove it first (don't know why)
  $('#cboxClose').click(); // Then this will close the box, $.colorbox.close() still doesn't work
  $.colorbox.init(); // Re-init, otherwise colorbox stops working
});
```

Hope it helps someone.

EDIT: Although that fixed the problem, the cause of the problem was I included jquery twice! (Thanks Jack)

Comment: See my answer to your question.  This is a very inefficient way of handling things.

Answer (score 1):

This may help someone .I have created a custom close button . My custom close button is coming on top right corner and can able to close also.
My code :

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('<div id="close" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 30px;"><img src="../img/close.png" alt="close"/></div>').appendTo('.yourparentDiv');

        $("#close").click(function() {
            jQuery('#cboxClose').click();
        });
    });
```

I was facing problem on closing the colorbox. It helped me.

Comment: This line can be useful: `jQuery('#cboxClose').click();` when everything else does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In notification.aspx you should have

```
<a id="btnClose" href="javascript:closeBox();">OK</a>
```

In the main page's javascript you should have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
...
function closeBox() {
  $.colorbox.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried putting this on the popup page, same thing. But thanks anyway

Comment: Same thing, nothing happens :( If I put return false it redirects to a blank page with text "false". Note that I am already calling the function correctly because the alert works fine. I just need to close the colorbox.

Comment: Unfortunately without seeing more of the code, I don't know what to tell you.  Its most likely an issue with the .js file being loaded in the wrong file and/or code is being executed improperly with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

// 3. Handle the dialog cancel button:

```
$("#CancelDeleteButton").click(function()
{
 $.fn.colorbox.close();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

most answers will work if you have the following conditions:
1. parent and child on the same domain
2. child has JQuery

in case you want to close the child box and you have any of these two conditions do the following:

in the parent do this:

```
$('document').ready(
    function () {
        window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
            $.colorbox.close();

        });
    });
```

in the child add a close button with the following js on click

```
 <input type="button" value="close" onclick="parent.postMessage('child frame', '*');" />
```