# Closing colorbox on clicking itself

Tags: jquery, colorbox

How can I close a colorbox when I click anywhere on the colorbox itself?

I am showing a hidden div as colorbox on click of a link

```
<div style="display: none">
  <div id="pop_box">
  Content goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to open the colorbox

```
<a id="seeTheOffer" target="_blank"> advertisement </a>
```

JQuery to open colorbox

```
$("#seeTheOffer").colorbox({ inline: true, height: "420px", href: "#pop_box" });
```

And this is what I tried so far.

Option 1:

```
$("#pop_box").click(function()
   {
     $("#seeTheOffer").colorbox.close();
   });
```

Option 2:

```
$("#pop_box").click(function()
   {
     parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
   });
```

Both these options give error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined "

From the view source of page, I can see below libraries being referred in head section

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js
jquery.colorbox.js (local copy)
colorbox.css (local copy)
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin and Hiral for right direction. Finally I was able to close the colorbox using

```
$('#cboxClose').click();
```

reference to: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406927/colorbox-bug-close-colorbox-from-a-link-or-button)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#email_popup_content").click(function(){
     $.fn.colorbox.close();
});
```

Comment: No luck yet. Please see the updated post with libraries I use

Answer (score 1):

Your wrote

> How can I close a colorbox when I click anywhere on the colorbox itself?

I'll assume **anywhere on the colorbox itself** means on the displayed popup.  Assuming that your first attempt was close.

Try this instead:

1. continue to use $.colorbox.close();
2. do not put inside a click event on #pop_box
3. instead, put it inside a selector ColorBox uses to wrap the displayed content
4. You'll have to put your code on the calling page BEFORE you instantiate the ColorBox.

Here is some code that uses a stupid alert as a verifying device::

```
$('#cboxWrapper').on('click', function() {
     alert('I am going to close Colorbox');
     $.colorbox.close();
```

`});`

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
```

The expected results is: clicking on the photos displayed in "group 1" now alerts and then closes the Colorbox.

Comment: The solution is very logical and should work. However, I got the alert on click, but then it gives below error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined "

Can it be due to some conflicts of libraries or so? I have updated my post with libraries I included.

Comment: In Chrome, when I clicked on error link, it pointed to statement
$.colorbox.close(); with message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined"
No other details found.

Comment: Maybe. More likely there is a javascript scope issue. If the content that is displayed in the popup opens in a new browser window or tab, and colorbox is not on that page, it won't be found and will lead to this type of error. Using Chrome's dev tools, from the console type $.colorbox. Do this on both of your pages. That will prove if colorbox is missing on the popped up page.