# I want to Add Close button on my pop up

Tags: html, css

I call a Colorbox page names enquiry.html 10 second after opening the base page IN enquiry.html page i added a close button but it does not work 
have a look on my code

In Head of base page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" />
```

In Body of base page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" async></script> 

<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" async></script>
<script>
  function openColorBox(){
    $.colorbox({
      iframe:true,
      width:"90%",
      height:"90%",
      href: "enquiry.html",
      onLoad: function() {
        $('#cboxClose').remove();
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(window).colorbox.close();
        }, 250000)
      }
    });
  }
  function countDown(){
    seconds--
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
    if (seconds === 0){
      openColorBox();
      clearInterval(i);
    }
  }
  var seconds = 10,
      i = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
</script>
```

in enquiry.html page

```
<input type="button" value="close" onclick=" $(window).colorbox.close()">
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p class="close">&nbsp;</p>
  </form>
```

But on click on Close button it does not Close

Please Help
Thanks In Advance

Comment: You can get help from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406927/colorbox-bug-close-colorbox-from-a-link-or-button

Answer (score 0):

you should try with `$.colorbox.close()` to close colorbox popup

refer this page for more details http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/